# Ubuntu 14.04 VPS won't boot the latest kernel on XEN

Tags: ubuntu, vps, xen

I have a XEN VPS and it's been running Ubuntu for some years now.
AUtomatic security upgrades are on and I've manually upgraded it continously and also done releas-upgrades whenever there's been a new release. All has been working great!

But now, after upgradeing to 14.04 LTS, the VPS won't boot the latest kernel (3.13.0-24) even though it's set to default. It always failback to 3.2.0-60 and for some reason the VPS seams very unresponsive, compared the before.

The support wrote in a ticket something about compiling my own kernel, with pvops enabled, but I'm not sure how to do that, or why I should compile my own kernel.

Doesn't Ubuntu support to be run on a XEN host?

Comment: No news on this, eh?

Comment: Who is your VPS provider? I'm seeing the same thing trying to boot trusty's 3.13 kernel. Although I have figured out that I can boot saucy's 3.11 kernel.

Comment: @BrianVisel I may have found a couple workarounds

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Try as I might I could not boot Ubuntu's 14.04 v3.13 kernel on amd64, nor could I boot a stock 3.15 kernel from kernel.org on amd64. My VPS provider indicated that the following error was being reported:

> (XEN) traps.c:405:d275 Unhandled invalid opcode fault/trap [#6] in domain 123 on VCPU 0 [ec=0000]

I suspect it has to do with some bug/incompatibility between an older version of Xen running on dom0 and recent versions (> 3.12) of the kernel running as domU. The good news is that — at least in my case — only amd64 seems to exhibit the issue.

Possible workarounds:

- Run a 32-bit version of the kernel
- Run a 3.12 or older version of the kernel (for example, [from saucy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-23-generic))
- Get your VPS provider to upgrade to the latest versions of Xen

  - (Well… I assume this would resolve the issue)